# How to access model type of hasMany array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I need to know the model type of a hasMany array.

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  addresses: DS.hasMany('address', { async: true })
})
```

With a regular model you can do `model.constructor.modelName` to find the type of the model.  So if I am passed the addresses array, how do I find out that the type of the array elements are `address`?

**Update:** Actually I solved my problem in a better way with the `createRecord()` function on the array which automatically adds a record of the correct type to the array. It would still be interesting to know if the above is possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parent.get('firstObject.children').then(
  children => console.log(children.get('type.modelName')) // child
);
```

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/foxigidafa/2/edit?js,output)

Comment: That assumes that collection has at least one object.  What if the collection is empty?

Comment: No it doesn't. It works even when children.length === 0... Why is the downvote?